# How to check if keys (Calendar) in hashmap are consecutive?

Tags: java, collections

I have a hashmap whose key type is Calendar, such as:

```
HashMap <Calendar, Student> map = new HashMap <Calendar, Student> ();
```

And once I sort the map by dates, I want to check if each calendar (key) in the map is consecutive per student name; for example, suppose the data in map is like this:

```
('10-01-2015', student1), ('10-02-2015', student1), ('10-03-2015', student1), ('10-10-2015', student1), ('10-11-2015', student2), ('10-13-2015', student2)
```

and so on.

Then what I want to have as a result is something like below:

```
student1: 10-01-2015 - 10-03-2015
student1: 10-10-2015
student2: 10-11-2015
student2: 10-13-2015
```

I think I am going to use TreeMap to sort the map, but I am not sure how to group the consecutive keys per value.
How would you approach?

Comment: I think navigableMap will help

Comment: Your design looks a bit weird to me, it would allow only one date/student combination .. is that what you want?

Comment: `Calendar`-sorting is inconsistent with `equals()` so it is pretty dangerous to use it as key in a sorted map like `TreeMap`.

Comment: @Sva.Mu   I added more data if it is clearer.

Comment: From what is posted you are probably in need of a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) (or `Map<Student, List<Date>>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop and inside of it do something like this..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(YOURKEY/DATE));
Calendar pd  = c;//previous Date
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
```

and now check if `c.getTime = dt.getTime`